# Getting number of time a rule is matched as unsigned int

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

So I have this, rather ugly rule in my `boost::spirit` parser;

```
qi::rule<Iterator, bool()> empty_brackets;
...
empty_brackets = (qi::token(LEFT_BRACKET) >> qi::token(RIGHT_BRACKET))
                     [ qi::_val = true ]
               ;
```

The rule is used as;

```
array_typeexp = (primitive_typeexp >> +(empty_brackets))
```

So what I really want, for the second argument (`qi::_2`), isn't a `std::vector<bool>`, but rather an `unsigned int`, describing the number of times `'empty_brackets'` was matched.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really unsure what you could need this for, but, hey :/

I'd suggest

```
empty_brackets    = lit('(') >> lit(')');
n_empty_brackets  = eps [ _val = 0 ] >> +empty_brackets [ ++_val ];

array_typeexp     = primitive_typeexp >> n_empty_brackets;
```

For simplicity I have made `primitive_typeexp` a "no-op", and therefore the outermost rules return *just* the `unsigned` value in this simple setup:

```
qi::rule<It, unsigned(), Skipper> array_typeexp, n_empty_brackets;
qi::rule<It, Skipper> empty_brackets, primitive_typeexp;
```

See a complete sample **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8aaf3c3781c920c4)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, unsigned(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(array_typeexp)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        empty_brackets    = lit('(') >> lit(')');
        n_empty_brackets  = eps [ _val = 0 ] >> +empty_brackets [ ++_val ];

        array_typeexp     = primitive_typeexp >> n_empty_brackets;

        // TODO
        primitive_typeexp = eps;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((array_typeexp)(n_empty_brackets)(empty_brackets)(primitive_typeexp));
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, unsigned(), Skipper> array_typeexp, n_empty_brackets;
    qi::rule<It, Skipper> empty_brackets, primitive_typeexp;
};

bool doParse(const std::string& input)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

    parser<It, qi::space_type> p;
    unsigned data;

    try
    {
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,data);
        if (ok)   
        {
            std::cout << "parse success\n";
            std::cout << "data: " << data << "\n";
        }
        else      std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

        if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
        return ok;
    } catch(const qi::expectation_failure<It>& e)
    {
        std::string frag(e.first, e.last);
        std::cerr << e.what() << "'" << frag << "'\n";
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    doParse("() () (     ) ()");
    doParse("()");
}
```

Comment: I'm needing it to match; `int[][][]`, that is multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: But I'll try this out, it looks rather promising.